# Publishing flutter apps with dependencies/plugins

Tags: flutter, plugins, package, dependencies, publishing

i have never published an app before and i am currently programming my own app to publish it after a few months.
Currently I program everything myself and don't use plugins, because i don't know exactly what will happen when an update for Android or iOS comes.
Do I have to adapt the version of the plugins then? and what if the responsible of the plugin does not release a new version? Can you then no longer use my app?

I am unfortunately still a beginner when it comes to these topics. I hope you can help me further. Then I would not have to program everything myself.

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on your first step. Publishing their own app is always a special event in a dev's life.

If your app doesn't depend on any external package, then you don't have to worry about anything.

If your app depends on other external packages, It is always preferred to keep the codebase updated. This might involve some code refactoring, but it is always worth it.

Things to keep in mind,

- If it's a UI package, it is fine, because the OS breaking changes won't affect the UI packages.
- If it's a functional package, Before using the package, make sure how reliable the maintainer is. Always go with the reputed packages or the packages with a lot of likes, see how many issues were closed. You don't have to worry about breaking changes, the maintainers will take care of that.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. So i can use external packages like https://pub.dev/packages/indexed_list_view without any problems?